# ¿Cómo utilizo el plugin Basic-CMIS en Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, cms, alfresco

he instalado el plugin basic-CMIS en mi wordpress y lo he configurado para que se conecte con Alfresco, pero a la hora de comprobar su funcionamiento visualizando un documento almacenado en Alfresco desde Wordpress, no encuentro nada para realizar esta acción. No se como puedo visualizar el contenido de Alfresco ni como acceder a estos documentos desde una entrada/post(por ejemplo).

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

encontré la solución a mi problema, revisando la utilización del plugin y como utilizar cmis en wordpress encontré lo siguiente:

Crear una entrada de wordpress -> Añadir widget de "shortcode" e introducir alguno de estos shortcodes.

Utiliza el `[cmis]` shortcode para encontrar el/los archivo/s y mostrarlo/s.

- Todos los documentos de una carpeta: `[cmis folder="/ruta_de_carpeta/Carpeta_Final"]`
- Todos los documentos de una carpeta (Incluyendo subcarpetas): `[cmis tree="/Ruta_carpeta/carpeta_final/"]`
- Documentos que contengan las palabras: `[cmis keywords="café pastas desayuno"]` (cualquier palabra que contenga el archivo).
- Documento por nombre. Debe incluir el simbolo '%': `[cmis name="Agenda%.doc"]` (Mostrará los archivos que comiencen por Agenda[algo mas] y terminen en .doc); En caso de querer especificar un nombre exacto: %nombre exacto.txt%.
- Combinar parametros: `[cmis folder="/documents" keywords="bacon" name="%menu%.pdf"]`

Cualquier otro aporte a esta respuesta se argradecerá. Un saludo.